# Connect a USB Digital-to-Analog Converter (DAC) to a monitor

Tags: audio-conversion

I have a Digital-to-Analog Converter (DAC) directly connected to my computer and want to also use it with my monitor (no USB port) which is connected to some other devices (such as gaming consoles). The monitor has a standard 3.5mm audio jack, but suffers from severe [crosstalk](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Crosstalk#In_audio).

[image: image of the DAC]

In other words, I'm trying to connect the DAC to my monitor, then connect my audio device to the DAC. I can use the PC as a power source.

Comment: It's unclear right now exactly what you're trying to achieve. Exactly what do you expect to connect to what?

Comment: @djsmiley2k: Sorry. I'm trying to connect the DAC to my monitor, then connect my audio device to the DAC. I can use the PC as a power source.

Comment: Something like this will work. (You would need 2) https://www.amazon.com/AmazonBasics-3-5mm-2-Male-Adapter-Cable/dp/B01D5H8KO2?psc=1&SubscriptionId=AKIAILSHYYTFIVPWUY6Q&tag=duckduckgo-ffab-20&linkCode=xm2&camp=2025&creative=165953&creativeASIN=B01D5H8KO2

Comment: @Pancakedinner: Someone posted an answer, hopefully you don't mind.

Comment: He took mine and added way more detail and Explain everything, I just posted a link to what you needed. Give it to him.

Comment: "Something like this will work. (You would need 2)" - do you mean that I have to purchase *two cables* or just than two RCA ends are required?

Comment: Depends on what you are doing exactly, I said two because I thought you where going to use with your monitor or something with Aux-in. I misunderstood you, You should be able to plug speakers into the headphone jack on that DAC. You only need one.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Those type of jacks on the DAC are called "RCA jacks."

Adapters exist to convert from RCA to 3.5mm.  Search your favorite online retailer for "RCA to 3.5mm adapter", the picture is from a similar search on Amazon as an example.

[image]

If the audio through the monitor's speaker is low quality, you may need to get a powered speaker set or connect the DAC to a stereo or surround receiver.  Typically these already have RCA jacks.

Comment: Is it possible to use the DAC with my computer at the same time? When I'm on my PC the computer operates as the audio source, not the monitor. Connected via USB, headphones/speakers are plugged in to the "phones" jack (see my picture).

Comment: Referring to your last paragraph, my monitor doesn't have internal speakers.

Comment: Unless your monitor has an audio *out* it's not making any sound, just accepting audio in.